# Import Variable from Python FilePath

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

I'm writing a clean up script from one of our applications and I need a few variables from a python file in a separate directory.

Now normally I would go:

```
from myfile import myvariable
print myvariable
```

However this doesn't work for files outside of the directory. I'd like a more targeted solution than:

```
sys.path.append('/path/to/my/dir)
from myfile import myvariable
```

As this directory has a lot of other files, unfortunately it doesn't seem like `module = __import__('/path/to/myfile.py')` works either. Any suggestions. I'm using python 2.7

EDIT, this path is unfortunately a string from `os.path.join(latest, "myfile.py")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a more targeted import using the [imp](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html) module. While it has a few functions, I found the only one that allowed me access to internal variables was `load_source`.

```
import imp
import os

filename = 'variables_file.py'
path = '/path_to_file/'

full_path = os.path.join(path_to_file, filename)

foo = imp.load_source(filename, full_path)

print foo.variable_a
print foo.variable_b
...
```